# Puppeteer - How to wait xhr to finish and check if it failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape the shipping section of an Aliexpress product page with puppeteer.

I need to wait for an XHR request to be loaded, and I have no idea how to do it. I researched a lot of possible methods, but I didn't find a fitting solution.

By now I came up with something like the following snippet, but it only intercepts a request.

```
product.client = await product.page.target().createCDPSession();

await product.client.send('Network.enable');

await product.client.send('Network.setRequestInterception', {patterns: [
  {urlPattern: '*', resourceType: 'XHR', interceptionStage: 'HeadersReceived'}
]});

await product.client.on('Network.requestIntercepted', async ({ interceptionId, request }) => {

  if(request.url.includes('freight')) {
    console.log('New freight intercepted');
    // I tried this but it doesn't work
    //await product.page.waitForResponse(request.url);
  }

  product.client.send('Network.continueInterceptedRequest', {
    interceptionId
  });
});
```

I thought also to use the events requestFailed and requestFinished, but it doesn't work.
I would really appreciate any hint, thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
I decided to analyse the XHR requests because it's loading dynamic content.

Comment: have you already tried to add any `{ waitUntil: 'xyz...' }` options on `page.goto`? because normally you shouldn't have any requests failed if the page loaded. alternatively, if the other un-important XHRs stealing the network and prevents the desired XHR to be loaded: you could filter out those that unneccesary.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I thought to analyse the XHR requests because they load only by clicking on certain elements. This way it sadly doesn't work just with waitUntil. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I see. Have you considered using a solution with only `page.waitForResponse`?  (I see you tried it in the condition but the line is commented)

Comment: I think that waitForResponse is the way to go here, I'm trying now more in this direction, thanks!